# Is there a "clever" way to solve this congruence?

Tags: number-theory

$p = 683$ is prime, and $(p-1) = 2\cdot 11\cdot 31$. Given this, how can I most efficiently solve $4^{11112} \bmod{p}$?

Since $11112 = 682\cdot 16 + 200$, I get $4^{200} \bmod{p}$, but now I'm left with the tedious task of solving this which will take some time, I think. The prime factorization of $(p-1)$ seems to hint to a simpler way to do this, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: hint: 683+341=1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of $2$  is a divisor of $682$, by *Lagrange's theorem*, i. e. one of $\;2, 11,31,62,341,682$. Clearly it is not $2$, and $2^{11}=2048=3\cdot 683-1\equiv -1\mod 683$, hence $4$ has order $11$.Thus $\;4^{11112}\equiv4^{11112\bmod 11}$ and $\;11112\bmod 11=2-1+1-1+1=2$, so
$$4^{11112}\equiv 4^2=16\mod 683.$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

- $\color\red{4^{11}}\equiv1\pmod{683}$
- $4^{11112}=(\color\red{4^{11}})^{1010}\cdot4^2$